# substring character vector in R using a pattern

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, character

I have the following character vector in R called x

```
[1] "0_pt8a"  "10_pt8a" "7_pt8a"  "5_pt8a"  "3_pt8a"  "2_pt8a"  "6_pt8a"  "9_pt8a"  "8_pt8a"  "4_pt8a" 
[11] "7_pt8b"  "1_pt8b"  "0_pt8b"  "5_pt8b"  "8_pt8b"  "3_pt8b"  "4_pt8b"  "12_pt8b" "11_pt8b" "9_pt8b" 
[21] "10_pt8b" "14_pt8c" "9_pt8c"  "4_pt8c"  "2_pt8c"  "1_pt8c"  "8_pt8c"  "13_pt8c" "7_pt8c"  "12_pt8c"
[31] "0_pt8c"  "11_pt8c" "15_pt8c" "3_pt8c"  "10_pt8c"
```

My goal is to output a list with only those with pattern than ends with _pt8a

desired output would be

```
"0_pt8a"  "10_pt8a" "7_pt8a"  "5_pt8a"  "3_pt8a"  "2_pt8a"  "6_pt8a"  "9_pt8a"  "8_pt8a"  "4_pt8a"
```

I tried multiple methods including

```
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "_pt8a"), paste, collapse=",")

substr(x, "^._pt8a")
```

Among other things from what I found on stackoverflow but none worked. I think this should be a simple thing but not sure why it is not working.

Comment: `grep("_pt8a",x,value=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks!! that's easier than I thought.

Comment: you could also use `x[endsWith(x, "_pt8a")]`